# button delegate in a tableview

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to embed a button per row inside a tableview. My botton are drawing correctly but are not reacting to any clicks.. Should I be setting flags for this column? so far I have something like:

```
    if index.column() == 14:
        flags |=  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable  | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
    return flags
```

And this is the delegate:

```
class AButton(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
mouse_isPressed = False

def __init__(self, parent = None):
    QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

def boundingRect(self):
    return QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 40, 40)

def paint(self, painter, option, widget = 0):
    opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionButton()

    opt.state = ((QtGui.QStyle.State_Sunken if self.mouse_isPressed else QtGui.QStyle.State_Raised) | QtGui.QStyle.State_Enabled)
    opt.text = self.text()
    opt.icon = self.icon()
    opt.rect = option.rect
    opt.palette = option.palette
    QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_PushButton, opt, painter)

def text(self):
    return QtCore.QString("hi")

def icon(self):
    return QtGui.QIcon()

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.mouse_isPressed = True
    print "HELLO"
    self.update()

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    self.mouse_isPressed = False
    self.update()
```

Is there any example out there I could look at?

thanks in advance,
Cris

Answer (score 0):

Qt delegates doesn't provide specific events handlers (like mousePressEvent, mouseReleaseEvent, ...) as QWidget does.
If you want to react to user actions you should reimplement the [`editorEvent`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstyleditemdelegate.html#editorEvent) method.
By the way, there is no such `'update'` method defined in `QStyledItemDelegate`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I got this now. I am using Editor methods to get my buttons to react. There is only one thing that bothers me, not sure if it is a limitation or something I can fix.
To be able to press a button, I need to "activate" the containing cell with a double click. Once the cell is active I can press the button. This could become confusing for your average user. Any ideas?